# can't use push_back for a array ros message in arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, rosmessage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Arduino code:**

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseArray.h>
 
ros::NodeHandle nh;

geometry_msgs::PoseArray array;
ros::Publisher p("array", &array);

void setup()
{ 
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(p);
}

void loop()
{  
  geometry_msgs::Pose pose;
  
  pose.position.x=1;
  pose.position.y=1;
  pose.position.z=1;

  array.poses.push_back(pose);
  
  p.publish(&array);
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(10);
}
```

Here is  simple test to publish a **PoseArray**. When I compile it, I got the errors like:

> /Users/Crazymumu/Desktop/array_test_1/array_test_1.ino:
> In function 'void loop()':
> array_test_1:37: error: request for
> member 'push_back' in
> 'array.geometry_msgs::PoseArray::poses',
> which is of pointer type
> 'geometry_msgs::Pose*' (maybe you
> meant to use '->' ?)
> array.poses.push_back(pose);
> ^ exit status 1 request for member 'push_back' in
> 'array.geometry_msgs::PoseArray::poses',
> which is of pointer type
> 'geometry_msgs::Pose*' (maybe you
> meant to use '->' ?)

I am not sure. This should be all right in original ROS environment. Any suggestions? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234961/can%27t-use-push_back-for-a-array-ros-message-in-arduino/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2016-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-05-23**:
Have you tried what the error suggest? I am not familiar with ROS Arduino, but it says that you must use `array.poses->push_back`

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2016-05-23**:
yes, I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use  array.poses[i]=pose; No vector available in arudino. [Also be aware that the arrays in the messages are not defined as vector objects.](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Messages)

---

Originally posted by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) with karma: 214 on 2016-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0